# ERROR - caught "NSInternalconsistencyException","API violation - element is a required parameter"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am getting an error what I am struggling to find any other related instances of the error. I am trying to create my test to be asynchronous using `expectationForPredicate` however when using this method it throws the error `caught "NSInternalconsistencyException","API violation - element is a required parameter"` on line 13.

Any idea why this error is happening and how can I result this

```
  let app = XCUIApplication()
    let alert = XCUIElement()
    let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let systemAlert = alert.buttons["OK"]

    testCase.addUIInterruptionMonitorWithDescription("Enable Notifications") { (alert) -> Bool in
            alert.buttons["OK"].tap()
        return true
    }

    self.buttons["Enable notifications"].tap()

    testCase.expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate, evaluatedWithObject: systemAlert, handler: nil)
    testCase.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)

    app.tap()

    self.tabBars.buttons["Nearby"].tap()
```

Comment: perhaps you are missing a parameter in the method...which method is giving this error? Just `option click` on it to see the method signature and see if you are missing a param

Comment: The signature method is `expectationForPredicate`but doesnt seem like anything is missing from the method signature...

Comment: see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1500569-expectation) I'm a bit confused about your signature, `expectationForPredicatebut` seems to be objectiveC-ish...

Comment: Hmm strange, I am going from what I have found on stackover flow and masiloti's blog [link] (http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/)

Comment: The code hasn't been updated for Swift3, still you *may* be able to access foundation in Swift with no issue, but sometimes signatures have changed and or creates a mismatch between new and old...you have to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Your alert is not a valid element from your app, as you've initialized it directly instead of derived it from your XCUIApplication instance. Therefore, the `systemAlert` that you pass into `expectationForPredicate` is not a valid XCUIElement either.

Change the assignment of `alert` to be derived from `app`, and that should fix your problem.

```
let alert = app.alerts.elementBoundByIndex(0)
```